# Extracting SharePoint Security Groups and List ID

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to extract the security groups on a SharePoint site along with the List id so that I can update another list that using these values in a look up field.

Novice with Sharepoint web services and looking for an easy way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code from where you get all the groups and their name and ids

```
SPGroupCollection grpcolls = web.Groups;
foreach(SPGroup grp in grpcolls)
{
     string grpid = grp.ID.ToString();
     string grpLoginName = grp.LoginName;
     string grpName = grp.Name;
}
```